# Kendo Grid: conditionally hide command button

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I want to hide the kendoGrid column on RoleBase. There are 6 users of my system for Manager,ProductManager & Supplier I do not want to show the column  and for other three I want column to be visible. 
My column defination:

```
 { command: { text: "Upload", hidden: '#if(ManagerRoleAccess== true || ProductManagerRoleAccess== true || SupplierRoleAccess== true)' }
```

I do not know what went wrong in this, the column hidden for all users.. Any help?

Comment: You can't show the column in a line and not show in another line. Either you show it or not at all. I mean, you can't show or not by a condition for each line. You have to set it at grid initialization or change it at some event, like `dataBound` ([check this out](https://dojo.telerik.com/OKobI)). Also, the [`hidden`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.hidden) parameter is **boolean** so you can't set a template for it. As you have set a string, it will always evaluate to **true**, that is why it's always hidden.

Comment: I am not sure that hidden even works for commands, when I inserted `hidden: true` into one of my commands on a grid it did nothing and I do not seem to see it mentioned anywhere in the configuration found on telerik's website.  https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.command.text  You could possibly just have a function which would evaluate to return that whole command config or none where you can actually do your check for what type of user they are

Comment: Hi Stephen &  DontVoteMeDown .. At the end I made my program run by function, but I was interested in template in "hidden" parameter (if any). because according to this http://dojo.telerik.com/uVAJoT kendo support  ternary operator..

Answer (score 1):

You were very close: the commands don't have a `hidden` field, but they do have [`visible`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.command#columnscommandvisible):

```
{ command: [{ name: "edit", visible: function(dataItem) { return dataItem.isSuperUser }}] }
```

Dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/ozONeSEG

**However**, your Dojo uses Kendo 2016.3.1028 and this param doesn't work in that version yet. If I'm not mistaken, it was introduced in version 2017.1.118.